# JavaScript Sourcemaps not requested

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, source-maps

I'm trying to debug some JavaScript built with closure compiler, running Chrome (54 stable) on Ubuntu.

I have my minified JavaScript file `foo.js` (loaded from a shell .html file) as well as a sourcemap file `foo.sourcemap`, and I'm serving them both on localhost using a simple python httpserver:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

`foo.js` ends with:

```
//# sourceMappingURL=/foo.sourcemap
```

I've verified that the 'use javascript sourcemap' setting is turned on.

However, I can see from the server logs that `foo.sourcemap` is never even requested from Chrome. What other things could I be missing which would cause the sourcemap file not to be loaded at all? I'm unsure how to debug from here.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the syntax for sourcemap comments has changed. Modifying this to:

```
//@ sourceMappingURL=/foo.sourcemap
```

Did the trick